# DNS lookup failed --- dig: couldn't get address for 'ns1.p34.dynect.net': failure

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, ns-record, twitter

I am a Network Admin from India, managing a large University Network of more than 15000 users.

Here goes my problem - >

My DNS is unable to get ip address for **ns1.p34.dynect.net**.
when i use `dig +trace twitter.com` on my DNS Server i get this messages:-

**dig: couldn't get address for 'ns1.p34.dynect.net': failure**

and this is happening with all those sites listed with `dynect.net` like
**twitter,linkedin,quora** etc.

Find the attached screen shot for the same message.

[image]

Right now I have temporally fixed (not actually fixed) the problem using Google DNS (8.8.8.8)

What could be the issue as It is able to resolve all other sites perfectlly.

Thanks

**Edit:**

As suggested in answer, I am attaching one more screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Do you really think it makes sense to use screenshots if they are just about **text in a Linux console**?? Do you think it is more fun to write something down from a screenshot than to copy and paste it from text?

Answer (score 2):

Please try following.

First, try whether you can get NS record of ns1.p34.dynect.net. It will output something similar. Look at the origin line where I get the value ns0.dynamicnetworkservices.net.

```
$nslookup -querytype=NS ns1.p34.dynect.net
Server:     10.10.10.54
Address:    10.10.10.54#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find ns1.p34.dynect.net: No answer

Authoritative answers can be found from:
dynect.net
    origin = ns0.dynamicnetworkservices.net
    mail addr = hostmaster.dyndns.com
    serial = 2013041600
    refresh = 10800
    retry = 1800
    expire = 604800
    minimum = 1800
```

Second, issue nslookup request for ns1.p34.dynect.net with the name server pointing to the origin server you get from step 1. See whether you can get answer similar to below. If you are not able to resolve, probably your network is not able to reach ns0.dynamicnetworkservices.net somehow.

```
$ nslookup ns1.p34.dynect.net ns0.dynamicnetworkservices.net
Server:     ns0.dynamicnetworkservices.net
Address:    208.78.68.100#53

Name:   ns1.p34.dynect.net
Address: 208.78.70.34
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested ... Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: How about telnet 208.78.68.100 53 ?

Answer (score 2):

removing query-source address * port 53; worked for me.  I have a question, do you know if anything changed recently as far as DNS. All these resolutions were working fine until about a week ago.  that's when we started seeing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have query-source address in your named.conf options, try removing that and see if that helps. I had this issue on some very old name servers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same faults since Monday.
Problem was resolved when i removed "query-source address * port 53;" from my named.conf